# Bootstrap grid not working inside a dynamic width container

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a requirement where I have to create 2 fixed width panels, one on right and one on left and I have to keep the center component responsive according to bootstrap classes.

I did something like this

Styles file

```
.c-row {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.c-row .c-col-left {
    width: 260px;
}

.c-row [class^='c-'] {
    float: left;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: white;
}

.c-row .c-col-center {
    background-color: #e6e7fb;
    width: calc(100% - (260px + 350px));
}

.c-row .c-col-right {
    width: 350px;
}
```

Markup

```
<div class="c-row">
  <div class="c-left">content</div>
  <div class="c-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">c1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-right">content</div>
</div>
```

So my problem here is: The grid inside center class isn't working, it works fine if I remove the style `width: calc(100% - (260px + 350px));` from center column.

is there any way I can still make it work without changing the custom grid outside?

Comment: Why are you using `float` **and** bootstrap which is flexbox based?

Comment: It's bootstrap 4, and I was using float because I just had to place them in 3 parts. This was easiest and most straight forward way

Comment: As i said, BS4 uses **flexbox** not float...so use those properties.

Comment: Ohh, sadly I don't know floats :-P
thanks for showing me the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flexbox which is integral to Bootstrap 4

```css
.c-row {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.c-row .c-left {
  flex: 0 0 260px;
  background: pink;
}

.c-row [class^='c-'] {
  height: 90vh;
}

.c-row .c-center {
  background-color: #e6e7fb;
  flex: 1;
}

.c-row .c-right {
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="c-row">
  <div class="c-left">content</div>
  <div class="c-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">c1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">c2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-right">content</div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vYBJLJq)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without custom flexbox use but only with the Bootstrap grid.

```css
.col,
[class*="col-"] {
  min-height: 90vh !important;
}

.c-left {
  width: 260px !important;
  background: lightpink;
}

.c-center-1 {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.c-center-2 {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}

.c-right {
  width: 350px !important;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="c-row row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-auto c-left">content</div>
    <div class="col c-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 c-center-1">c1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 c-center-2">c2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto c-right">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*(some `!important` just because how SO snippets work, see codepen demo)*

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/florianlacreuse/pen/RwbZpKm)